# Fixed navbar - don't scroll page behind, and make it scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a couple of issues with Bootstrap 4 `fixed-top` navbar:

1) It scrolls the page behind it when in collapsed view - How to prevent that?

2) You can't scroll the navbar down if the links are out of the view, as you can see in the example below, I have 8 links, and added `35px` paddings just to make them go out of the view. You cannot scroll down to them. Instead it scrolls the page behind it.

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding:35px!important;
}

p {
    padding-top:1000px;  /* to emulate scroll */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" width="35" height="35" alt="logo">
            <span>Logo</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 7</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 8</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<p class="text-center"><strong>I am content at the bottom</strong></p>
```

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of `<br>` tags you should probably use margin or padding in CSS. Just as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

This issue you can solve it by 2 ways

you can define a height for the `.navbar` class for example it can be `80px` and then the content behind it give it `padding-top: 80px` or `margin-top: 80px` **with the same value or even more to have some more space**

## UPDATE

just add breakpoint `@media screen and (max-width: 991px) { .navbar { height: auto } }`

```css
   body { height: 2000px; }

  .navbar { 
       height: 80px; 
    }
   @media screen and (max-width: 991px) { .navbar { height: auto } }

    p {
        padding-top:85px;  /* to emulate scroll */
    }
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">



    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
                <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" width="35" height="35" alt="logo">
                <span>Logo</span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 7</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item main-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link py-0 text-center" href="#">Link 8</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <p class="spacing text-center"><strong>I am content at the bottom</strong></p>
```

this is more dynamic way if you don't want to have a fixed height and you can define it with js like that you just get the **height** of the **header** and then give it as padding-top to the content you want

```
  var navH = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

    console.log(navH);

    var res = $('.spacing').css('padding-top', navH + 10);  /* 10 in case you want more space*/

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: check it out again i have updated the snippet its just needed some height for the body to be able to see how you can scroll down

Comment: It is still not working, and now the drop down is transparent

Comment: i have updated the snippet i just made the height in smaller devices auto  that you can just see the nav without any problem

Comment: But the problem is not fixed: I can see up to Link 6, and can't scroll to see all of the links, which is the same problem